# Why does this code output before even reading input?

Tags: c++, input, io, output

My code below outputs 0, the value of max_explode, before even reading in my input.  Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;

int N,cnt=0;
vector<int> arr;
bool seen[MAX+1];
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) seen[i]=false;
  int max_explode=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    int cow;
    cin >> cow;
    arr.push_back(cow);
  }
  sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
  cout << max_explode << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `N`?  Aha.  Issues like this should have been easily solvable if you simply inspected your code, printed out a few of the variables, or just used the debugger.  Also, I would stress that you shouldn't make a kneejerk attempt at using StackOverflow for things like this.  Be a little curious on your own part if code acts strangely.  Debug, inspect, and you would have been able to figure this out.

Comment: Oddly g++ 4.9 (`-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`) totally misses this.

Comment: @user4581301 There is nothing to warn about. `N` is a global and therefore will be initialized to zero. But of course that makes the program not do much. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Works as coded on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read input in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  int cow;
  cin >> cow;
  arr.push_back(cow);
}
```

However, `N` is never explicitly initialized.  Since it's a global variable, it's automatically initialized to `0`, and your loop never runs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small issue in your 7th line to be specific. You have defined the variable N but haven't initialized a value to it.